# How to return status code and proceed with code execution using plumber API

Tags: r, api, plumber

I created Plumber API which triggers code execution. Here is how my function looks like:

```
#* Echo the parameter that was sent in
#* @param msg The message to echo back.
#* @get /echo
function(msg=""){
  
  output <- some_function(msg)
  return(output)
}
```

My `some_function` take very long time to run and I would like plumber to return status code 202 and then proceed with function execution. Does anybody know how to achieve it? I tried plumber filters but it did not help.

Comment: Use the future package to run your function in a separate process

Comment: @HongOoi Thank you! I guess you mean Async plumber. I am searching web to find good example, but there are not too many. Do you have any simple illustrations?